# KDE Konsole: how to save and restore current session?

Tags: terminal, kde, konsole, kde5

KDE Konsole does not have a feature to save the current session (opened tabs, current directory etc.)

How can we save/restore the current session?

Comment: Actually, as of KDE 5.18.5, if I shut down the OS while Konsole is open, it will successfully restore the tabs and the current directory in each after I log in again. The scrollback buffer is lost though (as expected).

Comment: Does it work on Wayland though? I thought the built-in save and restore only worked on X.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create `~/.konsole/watcher.sh` and make it executable (`chmod 755 watcher.sh`) then add it to the startup applications.

We can start konsole in a restored mode with `konsole --tabs-from-file ~/.konsole/current-tabs` or with `~/.konsole/watcher.sh restore`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ~/.konsole/watcher.sh

# Watches the konsole qdbus messages and saves session state changes so they can be restored easily
# https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html

# Configuration
COMMAND=''
WATCH_INTERVAL_SECONDS=15
SAVEFILE_TERMINAL="${HOME}/.konsole/current-tabs"

# Restore if asked to
if [ "$1" = "restore" ] ; then
    echo "Restoring..."
    konsole --tabs-from-file ${SAVEFILE_TERMINAL} -e 'bash -c exit'&
fi

# Function to get the current sessions and write them to a file
function getSessions {
    pid=$(pgrep konsole -u $USER)
    local SESSIONS=$(qdbus org.kde.konsole-$pid | grep /Sessions/)
    if [[ ${SESSIONS} ]] ; then
       echo "# Most recent session list " $(date) > ${SAVEFILE_TERMINAL}
       for i in ${SESSIONS}; do
       local FORMAT=$(qdbus org.kde.konsole-$pid $i tabTitleFormat 0)
       local PROCESSID=$(qdbus org.kde.konsole-$pid $i processId)
       local CWD=$(pwdx ${PROCESSID} | sed -e "s/^[0-9]*: //")
       if [[ $(pgrep --parent ${PROCESSID}) ]] ; then
           CHILDPID=$(pgrep --parent ${PROCESSID})
           COMMAND=$(ps -p ${CHILDPID} -o args=)
       fi 
       echo "workdir: ${CWD};; title: ${FORMAT};; command:${COMMAND}" >> ${SAVEFILE_TERMINAL}
       COMMAND=''
       done
    fi
}

#Update the Konsole sessions every WATCH_INTERVAL_SECONDS seconds
while true; do sleep ${WATCH_INTERVAL_SECONDS}; getSessions; done &
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really useful!

Comment: A few notes for others using this code:
1. Don't include the word `konsole` in your script name or it would break. 2. This won't support more than one konsole apps running. 3. It may not work if you try to run it from a shell terminal, kde needs to run it directly

Comment: This script doesn't work: `./watcher.sh: line 22: qdbus: command not found`

Comment: You can use `pgrep ^konsole$` or `pgrep --exact konsole` to only match the Konsole process, thus letting you save this script with whatever name you want. Also, if `qdbus` is not found, you probably want to install `qt5-tools` (or equivalent in your distro).

Comment: The `CHILDPID` logic is flawed if the user has executed multiple commands in background (via `&` or `bg`), as it would return multiple PIDs.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired [by the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593779), I've created my own script to save and load Konsole snapshots:

> https://github.com/denilsonsa/small_scripts/blob/master/konsole_snapshot.py

The usage is pretty simple:

```
./konsole_snapshot.py --help

# Use this to save a snapshot:
./konsole_snapshot.py --save

# Use this to load a snapshot (i.e. launch Konsole):
./konsole_snapshot.py --load
```

My script aims to fix all the shortcomings I found in the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593779). Specifically, you can name this script whatever name you want, and it supports saving multiple windows at once.

It has a few limitations: no support for splits or different layouts (difficult to implement using the current Konsole API), it doesn't save custom tab titles (it can be implemented, but within certain limits), it doesn't save the current command (which is good, otherwise it can be potentially dangerous). To overcome these limitations it is probably better to add proper session support into Konsole itself, instead of hacking more convoluted scripts.